# python for loop issue

Tags: python, python-3.6

I currently have this as an assignment. I have written the code below, but there seems to be an issue as the calculations keep on adding. Is there a way to restart the for loop?

There are 7 employees. Write a program with nested loops, to ask the yearly salary of each employee for 5 years.  Your program should keep track of the highest salary, lowest salary, and  calculate the average salary  of each employee. After you collect each employees data, display the highest salary, lowest salary, and   average salary for that employee.

```
totalsalary = 0
salaryhigh = 0
salarylow = 10000000
employee = 0   

for employee in range(1,4):
    print("Please enter the 5 year salaries of Employee#",employee,":")
    for year in range(1,6):
        salary = int(input('Enter you salary:'+""))
        totalsalary = totalsalary + salary
        if(salary > salaryhigh):
            salaryhigh = salary
        if(salary < salarylow):
            salarylow = salary
    avesalary = totalsalary/5
    print('Total Salary entered for 5 years for Employee#',employee,':',totalsalary)
    print("Average is:",avesalary)
    print("Highest Salary entered is:",salaryhigh)
    print("Lowest Salary entered is:",salarylow)
    print("------------------------------------")
```

Comment: I dont see the problem, that should work. Except for the unexpected indent in line 6, but I think you dont have that in your code.

Comment: It does work, but the issue is that when you reach employee 3 it adds the previous two employee calculations into the calculations for employee 3.

Comment: Try to put `totalsalary=0 `, `salaryhigh=0`, `salarylow=float("inf")` inside the first `for` loop, so they can be re-defined (set to these default values) on each iteration

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help, I definitely appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Your first three lines should be run for each employee, so they should be inside the outer for loop. The fourth line doesn't really do anything: your for-loop resets the employee number. Also, your for-loop does only three employees, but you state that there are seven employees. It's generally recommended that you set the number of employees at the beginning and then use that in the following code, so it's clear what the number represents and it's easier to keep track of and change the number. E.g.

```
number_of_employees = 7
for employee in range(0,number_of_employees):
    ...
```